# How can I change the "active image" of an object via python for baking?

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine, baking

I want to bake to an image via script.

Is there a way to set the "active image" of an object in python?
Alternatively, is there another way to use blender internal to bake to an image via python?

Comment: Check the references of [`Image(Id)`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72_release/bpy.types.Image.html#bpy.types.Image) (at the bottom of the page). It's either `MeshTextureFace` or `MeshTexturePoly`. I guess it's the second one. `mesh.uv_textures.active.data[poly_index].image`

Comment: Thanks, this works. I now use the following code to set the active image: `for d in mesh.uv_textures.active.data: d.image = image`